# How to reduce time between drags?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I wanted to know whether the is a way to reduce time between drags of draggable element. So when you drag an item that is draggable after releasing it has a short period of time until you can drag another item, so I wanted to know if there is a way and if there is, then how, can I reduced time of mentioned before periods?

Comment: Are you setting a delay? I am not sure what you are referring to otherwise. Can you post your code and/or demonstrate?

Comment: Well there is no code yet, because I can't find and option in documentation that would allow me to do it. And no, I am not setting delay, but I trying to find out is it possible

Comment: If there is no code how do you know there is a delay? This doesn't make sense at all. And there is a delay option for jquery ui draggable, but if you set it to 0 there is no delay.